# How to replicate the behavior on design time of Location and Font property (To give an example)

Tags: c#

I want to set a property which contains other properties inside (Like font or Location Properties), I've done the following:

```
class Example:DataGridView
{
    private PlusProperties X;

    public Example()
    {
        X = new PlusProperties();
        AdditionalProperties = X;

    }

    [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true), System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public PlusProperties AdditionalProperties
    {
        get { return X; }
        set
        {
            X = value;
        }
    }
}

public class PlusProperties
{
    private Color Pcolor = Color.DimGray;
    private Color Ccolor = Color.DimGray;

    public PlusProperties()
    {

    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true), System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public Color ParentColor
    {
        get { return Pcolor; }
        set
        {
            if (value != Pcolor)
            {
                Pcolor = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true), System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public Color ChildColor
    {
        get { return Ccolor; }
        set
        {
            if (value != Ccolor)
            {
                Ccolor = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

How can achieve the same behavior on design time (I mean show the properties of the class)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you need `ExpanableObjectConverter` (an attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a class that inherits `ExpandableObjectConverter` and add a `TypeConverter` attribute to your class that uses it. See the following example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perfect! That totally did it. Thank you for your help!